# Is public function safe to use in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Is public function safe to use in cakephp ? As i know public functions can be accessed through URL. I am new in cakephp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

**For standard Controller functions (aka Actions), it's standard practice to use `public` functions.**

Does that make them "safe"?  There is no way to answer that.  Really depends on what you're trying to secure, and what other methods you're using to secure it.

There will never be a point where someone should answer the question "is it safe".  But yes, as a rule, any function you want to access via a URL will be `public`.  It's up to you to determine what additional security measures you want to implement.  For instance, using the AuthComponent to determine if they're logged in, then comparing the User's "role" against valid roles that should have access to that method...etc.

Comment: I have a function (no arguments) which performs some database related manipulation. I want that only authentic users can call this function. Actually i called it in some other lines of code which is save. But i don't want that anyone who know the name of function , calls it by specific URL.